# How can I fill a string with a character up to the exact length?

Tags: string, scala

I have strings with different length, I want to fill them by symbol space, for example, to get string of the same length.

For instance, I have:

```
"1"
"3"
"12"
```

I need to get next result:

```
"  1"
"  3"
" 12"
```

Where all strings have length equals 3.

**Additional question:**
Or maybe you know, how to initialize string of exact length that is filled one symbol. For example, String that has 5 space symbols.

`"     "`

Comment: 1. Use String format interpolation: `f"$i%3s"` 2. A simple multiplication operator `" " * 5`

Answer (score 1):

You could use Scala API [padTo](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/collection/StringOps.html#padTo%28len%3AInt%2Celem%3AChar%29%3AString) to do what you need.

The only difference is that `padTo` appends elements but you need it to prepend. It's easy to do it with double `reverse`

```scala
def padLeft(string: String, size: Int, char: Char) = {
  string.reverse.padTo(size, char).reverse.mkString
}
```

Now, you can call it as following

```scala
padLeft("1", 3, ' ') .ensuring(_ == "  1")
padLeft("3", 3, ' ') .ensuring(_ == "  3")
padLeft("12", 3, ' ').ensuring(_ == " 12")
```

`ensuring` is added to assert that the value equals to the expected one.

If you want to create a string filled with the same element, you can do it via collections API. For example this way

```
val string = LazyList.fill(5)(' ').mkString
string.ensuring(_ == "     ")
```

Comment: It works but the performance is bad. It uses an imuutable Vector, it reverses it two times and then it has to call mkString to join.

Answer (score -1):

```
  def leftPad(str: String, length: Int, char: Char): String = {
    val diff = length - str.length
    if (diff <= 0) str
    else {
      val sb = new StringBuilder
      for (_ <- 0 until diff) sb.append(char)
      sb.append(str).toString()
    }
  }
```